# Properly insert breaks in titles on the profile's reputation page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, responsive-design, reputation-page

I was browsing a user's profile, when I saw this monstrosity:

[image]

In the screenshot, the first and third line look fine. 
The last line looks okay-ish. I'm impartial if the title should break here, or that the timestamp should move to a newline.

The second line however just looks plain ridiculous, with it taking up 4 lines, where two would have sufficed, if the title would break at more logical points.

The div is defined as `<div class="d-flex g4 p8 py2 md:p6 fw-wrap bb bc-black-075">`
Removing `fw-wrap` produces this:

[image]

At a first glance, this has no negative impact on responsiveness, but I could of course be wrong.